# How to change a string into another format?

Tags: php, string

So I have the following string like this:

```
1)what is capital of india?a)bangloreb)delhic)Hyderabad2)what is capital of telangana?a)hydb)khammamc)warangal
```

And I want to change it to:

```
1)what is capital of India?
A)Bangalore
B)Delhi
C)Hyderabad

2)what is capital of telangana?
A)Hyd
B)khammam
C)waranagal
```

Can someone give me any advises or hints how I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also add your current attempt(s) to your question.

Comment: ever seen this symbol? `<br>` and `<p>`

Comment: `preg_replace('~(?=\w\))~', '\n', $str)`

Comment: Hi sir,but if its dynamic data,means I'm getting data from database nearly 300 questions in the above format

Comment: how is this being stored in the db?

Comment: I had questions 1)...2)....390)....I want split every question individually

Comment: sounds like the db need to be normalized, but your not proving enough information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reformat a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689820/how-to-reformat-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data ="1)what is capital of india?a)bangloreb)delhic)Hyderabad2)what is capital of telangana?a)hydb)khammamc)warangal";
$data= str_replace("a)"," A)","$data");
$data= str_replace("b)"," B)","$data");
$data= str_replace("c)"," C)","$data");
$data= str_replace("d)"," D)","$data");

echo str_replace("2)"," <br/>2)","$data");
```

?>

Run this code this will help you.

Comment: Hi sir,its dynamic data,I'm getting 300 questions from database.

Comment: you can use first four str_replace as it is and for line break use your logic to break the line for new question.

Comment: I had questions 1)...2)....390)....I want split every question individually ,its dynamic data

Answer (score 0):

Using @Avinash Raj answer, here's the code snippet :

```
$str = "1)what is capital of india?a)bangloreb)delhic)Hyderabad2)what is capital of telangana?a)hydb)khammamc)warangal";

$str = preg_replace('~(?=\w\))~', '<br/>', $str );
echo $str ;
```

The expected output is :

```
<br/>1)what is capital of india?<br/>a)banglore<br/>b)delhi<br/>c)Hyderabad<br/>2)what is capital of telangana?<br/>a)hyd<br/>b)khammam<br/>c)warangal
```

wich results to :

1)what is capital of india?
a)banglore
b)delhi
c)Hyderabad
2)what is capital of telangana?
a)hyd
b)khammam
c)warangal

### UPDATE:

Code updated to Capitalize first letter.

```
<?php

$str = "1)what is capital of india?a)bangloreb)delhic)Hyderabad2)what is capital of telangana?a)hydb)khammamc)warangal";

$str = preg_replace('~(?=\w\))~', '|', $str );
$arr = explode('|', $str);

for ($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++) {
    $value = $arr[$x];
    $arr[$x] = ucfirst($value);
}

$arr = implode("<br/>", $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: how about capitalization of `a)` to `A)`

Comment: Code was updated and tested to use Capital letter for the first Char.  Please accept answer if this works for you.