# How to reformat a string

Tags: php, html

I have the following string:

> 1)what is capital of india?a)bangloreb)delhic)Hyderabad2)what is capital of telangana?a)hydb)khammamc)warangal

How can I change it to:

> 1)what is capital of India?
>   A)Bangalore
>   B)Delhi
>   C)Hyderabad
>
> 2)what is capital of telangana?
>   A)Hyd
>   B)khammam
>   C)waranagal

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data ="1)what is capital of india?a)bangloreb)delhic)Hyderabad2)what is capital of telangana?a)hydb)khammamc)warangal";
$data= str_replace("a)"," A)","$data");
$data= str_replace("b)"," B)","$data");
$data= str_replace("c)"," C)","$data");
$data= str_replace("d)"," D)","$data");

echo str_replace("2)"," <br/>2)","$data");
```

?>

Comment: $str = preg_replace('~(?=\w\))~', '<br/>', $str );

When Im using this...

I'm getting output as below

(
A)....(
B)....(
C)....(
D)....

But I want as below
(A)....
(B)....
(C)....
(D)....

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$data = "1)what is capital of india?a)bangloreb)delhic)Hyderabad2)what is capital of telangana?a)hydb)khammamc)warangal";
$data = preg_replace('/([0-9]+)\)/', "<br/>", $data);
$data = array_filter(explode("<br/>", $data));
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $val = str_replace("a)", " A)", $val);
    $val = str_replace("b)", " B)", $val);
    $val = str_replace("c)", " C)", $val);
    $val = str_replace("d)", " D)", $val);
    echo $key . ") " . $val . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: I want to separate each question by its number,plz help me

Comment: @Sangeetha Have you tried above code? In the above code you get sepret data of each question in `$data`.... You can try `print_r($data);` before `foreach` loop....

Comment: $str = preg_replace('~(?=\w\))~', '<br/>', $str );

When Im using this...

I'm getting output as below

(
A)....(
B)....(
C)....(
D)....

But I want as below
(A)....
(B)....
(C)....
(D)....I don't want break after "("